# How to have a Accordian with all menus collapsed by default

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have a accordian menu with 4 main categories. each categories have a set of sub categories within. By default, the first set is open. I would want all the menus, collapsed by default. Only when the category is clicked, the sub categories show up.

This is the script I am using..

```
<SCRIPT>
    $("#accordion > li").click(function(){
        if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();
</SCRIPT>`
```

Comment: can you post HTML code as well??

Comment: is't it obvious, its $('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show() that leaving it open

Comment: @deez nutz i am sorry, am not much into javascript. Got the code from a google search. Just dint know how to go arround with the collapsed menu on default

Comment: I don't get downvoting on this site.  This question has a clear problem, enough code to replicate the problem and solve it so why did it get a downvote.  If it's just because the OP doesn't know the answer, well isn't that what this site is for, to help people who need aren't as good as others at programming and need a bit of help with something they don't understand? Anyway +1 from me to make up for it

Comment: thank you @Pete Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line at the end:

```
$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();
```

This is what is causing the first option to be opened when it loads

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. Worked perfect.